# Installing USB device on VMware Workstation Machine

Tags: usb, vmware-workstation

I need to install a USB device (Web Camera and a Flatbed Scanner) on my virtual machine (Windows XP SP3) running in VMware Workstation. These devices are already installed on my host machine (also Windows XP SP3).

When I try to connect the device "VM->Removable Devices->Logitech USB Device->Connect (Disconnect from Host)", my host machine raises the "Hardware Installation" dialog for the newly detected device "VMware USB Device". After I click "Continue Installation", a new dialog appears displaying:

> **Insert Disk**
>
> Please insert the Compact Disk labeled
>   'VMware USB Driver Disk' into your CD-ROM...

I understand I need a driver in order to install this device, but where do I find this driver/disk/etc.?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the second dialog (Insert Disk...) I needed to provide the path to the *vmusb.sys* file, which by default is located here: "c:\Program Files\VMware\VMware Workstation\vmusb.sys". I browsed to this file, selected it, and it worked...